# Delete a specific dataset in a couchbase db by nativescript vue?

Tags: nativescript, couchbase, nativescript-vue, couchbase-lite

There is a couchbase database locally saved with cats in it.
A click on a specific cat, I want to delete it from the db.

Following code is for to add a cat to db:

```
methods: {
    addCat() {
        let documentId = database.createDocument({
            "name": randomName(),
            "age": getRandomInt(1,10),
            "id": _uniqueId('tttbbb')
        });
        this.cats = getCats();
    },
```

How may I get the DocumentID from the clicked cat (record) for deleting it?
Is the DocumentID automatically stored in the recordset?
I could not find it, thats why I added a id.

Thanks very much for your help.

Best regards Juergen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating your object you need to set id. I found this method the easiest way to find what you are looking for to delete.

```js
let documentId = database.createDocument({
                "name": randomName(),
                "age": getRandomInt(1,10)
            },"tttbbb");
```

```
createDocument(data: Object, documentId?: string): any;
```

You will need to retrieve `documentID` to delete it.

```
deleteDocument(documentId: string): any;
```

Comment: Does this mean, that i set my documentID myself, with self generated data?

Comment: CouchDB has document IDs but couchbase lite does not have auto document IDs

Answer (score 1):

When using Couchbase Lite, you can specify document id or let the id being generated. Not sure what CBL version you are using, here are two ways, you can do when using 2.x version.

```
// Specified ID
let document = MutableDocument(id: "YOUR OWN ID", data: [...])
database.saveDocument(document)

// Auto-generated ID
let document = MutableDocument(data: [...])
database.saveDocument(document)
let id = document.id // The generated id
```